# Switch display from 3.5 inch kedei LCD TFT back to HDMI monitor view

Tags: raspbian

I have my RPi3 successfully connected with kedei 3.5 inch touchscreen v6.3 with the driver that I downloaded from kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html. However, I **cannot switch back to HDMI view on my TV (from 3.5inch LCD display to TV screen)**. I have tried to run the "LCD_restore" file that I got from the driver .tar file but there is error when running it, (in multiple times saying: no such file or directory); for example, when I ran the line: "sudo cp ./backup/kernel.img /boot/kernel.img". 
note: I put my LCD_show_v6_1_3 folder on desktop
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image, It looks like you might not have marked the `LCD_hdmi` file as executable.

```
chmod +x LCD_hdmi
```

should make it executable. Then if you run it again it should work.

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick so that people know it's been solved. Plus you'll get reputation